# How to cause recompile of ASP.NET 5 RC 1 application in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core

With previous pre-releases of ASP.NET 5, when an application was deployed to Azure and I edited the files inside approot (compiled ones, e.g. HomeController.cs), it would trigger a recompile of the site and my changes would be visible on the next request of the live site. This no longer happens with in RC1. I can trigger a recompile by touching web.config, but I was wondering if there was another way to signal that the application needed to be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 5 natively doesn't have auto-restart features as ASP.NET previous had. In ASP.NET 5 this becomes the responsibility of the Web host - IIS in your case and if you use IIS you can use the old tricks like touching Web.Config to cause reload of an application.

Alternately you can run an external file monitoring utility on your server to trigger updates when files change but that's a bit more difficult to do if you're running on an Azure web site.